# Accurately measure yaw using Rotation Vector Sensor

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors, euler-angles

I am trying to measure the angle about the Z-axis(yaw) of an android device. I attempted to do this by using a [Rotation Vector sensor](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types#rotation_vector).
The reported angles, however, are inaccurate.

For example, if I rotate the phone 90 degrees couter-clockwise, the angle changes by about 30 degrees.

Is there any way to fix this so that the angles are more accurate (ie. if I physically rotate the phone by *θ* degrees, the reported angle should also change by *θ* degrees)?

Also, could this inaccuracy arise from the device's lack of a gyro sensor?

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    float qw = event.values[3], qx = event.values[0], qy = event.values[1], qz =event.values[2];
    float mag = (float)Math.sqrt(qw*qw + qx*qx + qy*qy + qz*qz);
    qw = qw/mag;
    qx = qx/mag;
    qy = qy/mag;
    qx = qz/mag;

    angle = Math.atan2(2.0f * (qw * qz + qx * qy),
            1.0f - 2.0f * (qy * qy + qz * qz)) + Math.PI;
    tvAngle.setText(Math.round(Math.toDegrees(angle));
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```